# Force u-boot out of fastboot mode

Tags: boot, bootloader

[This is a cross post from U&L SE]

I've made a mistake and flashed some hardware with an incorrect version of u-boot. The hardware differs from the hardware that I built u-boot for very little, but one of the key differences is the lack of dip switches.

The u-boot that's on the target looks at a switch (sw22) and immediately jumps into fastboot mode. This means I don't have a u-boot command line, which is how we reflash the bootloader (just fatload into a specific address and then copy over the old bootloader). I have a serial (over USB) connection to the device, as well as a fastboot connection (but this happens either connected or not)

What I've tried:

```
fastboot reboot
fastboot reboot-bootloader
fastboot -w (wipe everything)
```

Every time, the board just resets back into fastboot mode. Is there a way to force u-boot out of fastboot mode, and back into regular command-line mode?

Comment: Have you tried using fastboot to flash a new (correct) u-boot image?

Comment: How is that done? The fastboot command doesn't recognize the u-boot binary, as the u-boot that's on there would have to be provisioned for a u-boot partition.

Comment: The intent was to delete the original as was mentioned in the comments (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/570241/force-u-boot-out-of-fastboot-mode?noredirect=1#comment1060860_570241). I voted to close and move and that was the response I received

Comment: I don't have a fastboot system to hand, but something along the lines of `fastboot flash ${offset-or-partition} ${image}` should get you pointed in the right direction... Alternatively you could load and jump into a "correct" u-boot, and use that to flash itself.

Comment: There are likely other options as well, like a ROM bootloader... what's the processor / board?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share that information. I tried `fastboot flash 0xaddress u-boot.bin` and get met with "cannot find partition 0xaddress". The bootloader is stored in a different flash chip than everything else

Comment: Without more information we can't really help you out much... surely the processor in use isn't super secret?... There are potentially a number of other (non-`fastboot`) options available to you. Did you try `fastboot boot ${image}`? It's [supposed to be](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/fastboot.1.html) used to load a kernel, so you should be able to do that at least... you may be able to load and run a uboot image that way too.

Comment: Appreciate the help, and I'll give those a go. Unfortunately I'm not the one in control of the confidentiality. Loading a u-boot image over another one is an interesting solution

Comment: @Attie your comments allowed me to boot a new u-boot. If you'd like to post an answer I will mark it as correct

Comment: Glad to hear it! Feel free to post your own answer, with specific commands and syntax used (I can't provide this at the moment).